# run python parameters in Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, bert-language-model

I am running a python file in Google Colab and getting an error. I am following a bert text classification example from this link;

```
https://appliedmachinelearning.blog/2019/03/04/state-of-the-art-text-classification-using-bert-model-predict-the-happiness-hackerearth-challenge/
```

I followed the tutorial as described  and I am at the final step to run the code snippet below in colab,

```
python run_classifier.py 
--task_name=cola 
--do_train=true 
--do_eval=true 
--do_predict=true 
--data_dir=./data/ 
--vocab_file=./cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/vocab.txt 
--bert_config_file=./cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/bert_config.json 
--init_checkpoint=./cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/bert_model.ckpt 
--max_seq_length=400 
--train_batch_size=8 
--learning_rate=2e-5 
--num_train_epochs=3.0 
--output_dir=./bert_output/ 
--do_lower_case=False
```

I know in the Colab i must run the python file like this;

```
!python run_classifier.py
```

But how can i set the other parameters like in the script. It throughs errors. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

You should put the `\` symbol between parameters. For example, your code would be:

```
!python run_classifier.py \
--task_name=cola \
--do_train=true \
--do_eval=true \
--do_predict=true \
--data_dir=./data/ \
--vocab_file=./cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/vocab.txt \
--bert_config_file=./cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/bert_config.json \
--init_checkpoint=./cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/bert_model.ckpt \
--max_seq_length=400 \
--train_batch_size=8 \
--learning_rate=2e-5 \
--num_train_epochs=3.0 \
--output_dir=./bert_output/ \
--do_lower_case=False
```

This worked for me in another example.